# Usage of stream in java8 for multiple get methods

Tags: java, java-8

```
String serviceClass = railsComponent
    .getRailOffer()
    .getRailProducts()
    .get( 0 )
    .getRailProduct()
    .getFareBreakdownList()
    .get( 0 )
    .getPassengerFareList()
    .get( 0 )
    .getPassengerSegmentFareList()
    .get( 0 )
    .getCarrierServiceClassDisplayName();
```

this returns me valid serviceClass value.

I wanted to convert this code with the help of java8 stream concept.

I tried with below

```
String serviceClass = railsComponent.getRailOffer().getRailProducts().stream()
                .map(railProcucts -> railProcucts.getRailProduct().getFareBreakdownList().stream()
                .map(fareBreakdownType -> fareBreakdownType.getPassengerFareList().stream()
                .map(passengerFareType -> passengerFareType.getPassengerSegmentFareList().stream()
                .map(segmentFareType -> segmentFareType.getCarrierServiceClassDisplayName())))).findFirst().orElse(null).toString();
```

which is returning me value as java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@5585427d .

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how I get proper value in this case.

Comment: Not that it's what you asked but the null case here is absolutely going to throw a `NullPoiinterException` at you if you call `toString()` on null.  `findFirst().orElse(null).toString();`

Comment: why do you want to use stream here ?

Comment: I wanted to avoid multiple null checks. so trying to use this.

Comment: @MikeAdamenko because it was almost the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583350/multiple-null-checks-handling-in-java8). He don't get the difference between Stream an Optionnal

Comment: Then you want [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-), not a stream.

Comment: you have a `Stream<Stream<Something>>` as the result before `findFirst`

Comment: Did you mean to use `flatMap` instead of `map`?

Comment: yes. if that's the case

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a `Stream` here?  I think your first attempt is a lot cleaner and a lot nicer.

Comment: @JoeC I want to avoid checking for null for each cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using here `map` instead of `flatMap`, so you should use:

```
railsComponent.getRailOffer().getRailProducts().stream()
    .flatMap(rp -> rp.getFareBreakdownList().stream())
    .flatMap(fb -> fbl.getPassengerFareList().stream())
    .flatMap(pf -> pfl.getPassengerSegmentFareList().stream())
    .map(psf -> psf.getCarrierServiceClassDisplayName())
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
```

Be aware that will return String or `null`, so you cannot just add `toString()` without check.